# Какая функция отвечает за открытие шторки nav drawer?

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

В своем приложении я работаю с меню `Navigation Drawer`. У меня возник вопрос - какая функция отвечает за открытие шторки. Имеется в виду - есть гамбургер, на который нажав можно открыть список с пунктами меню, или просто открыть свайпом. Вот мне интересно какая функция отвечает за создание там элементов меню. Вопрос вызван тем, что мне нужно самостоятельно заполнять `title` + `subtitle`+`imageview` которые есть в шапке меню. Эта шапка состоит из view элементов которые я хочу заполнять данными с сервера, и мне нужно что-бы запрос на информацию отправлялся не при создании всей менюшки, а только когда открывается шторка, потому-что при создании меню и так отправляется запрос, а два запроса запускаются очень криво. Поэтому интересно как отправить запрос только при активации шторки.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#OpenClose

Answer (score 1):

drawerLayout.close(navigationDrawer)